# Count the number of cells with red text in excel file using xlrd in python

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using xlrd to open an excel file in my computer and I have numbers in red, numbers in black, I want to count the number of numbers in red, do anyone have any idea how to approach this?

```
import xlrd

filename = "data.xls"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(filenmae, formatting_info = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd

filename = 'data.xls'
book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename, formatting_info=True)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
max_row = sheet.nrows
max_col = sheet.ncols
count = 0
for row in range(max_row):
    for col in range(max_col):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, col)
        frmt = book.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
        font = book.font_list[frmt.font_index]
        count = count+1 if font.colour_index == 10 else count

print(count)
```

You may need to play around with the colour index to find the correct one for your red. I just grabbed a cell that I knew was red and checked the colour index. More info can be found [here](https://pythonhosted.org/xlrd3/general.html?highlight=colour%20index#the-palette-colour-indexes)

Comment: That's great! But why does empty sell gives same font.colour_index as cell with black text?? Any method to deal with that? And it seems when my filename is 'data.xlsx', this doesn't work, so what should we do?

Comment: @Sally: `font.colour_index` is a `style` assigned to a cell, **not** to a value. Therefore **empty** Cells does have the same `style`.  Test if `cell.value` is **not** empty to count only Cells with values.

Comment: @Sally The formatting_info parameter of the open_workbook method doesn't work for .xlsx files. Try saving it as a .xls first if you can.

Comment: @ATK7474  do you know how to do this for xlsx files?